# Cyrillic symbols in a tweet

Tags: php, api, twitter

I use EpiTwitter , it works fine , but when $varx have cyrillic symbols

```
$varx="Привет";
$status=$Twitter->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $varx));
```

api answers

```
'error' => string 'Could not authenticate with OAuth.' 
  'request' => string '/statuses/update.json'
```

i've tryed many variations like urlencode,json_encode on $varx , but it post answers of this functions
my file is utf-8 without BOM , also i've tryed ansi

any ideas ?

Comment: Are you positive that non-cyrillic requests authenticate correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artem, i think problem not in cyrillic symbols. Did you register your application in twitter (http://twitter.com/oauth_clients)? You will get *consumer key* and *consumer secret*. Then define it in your php application:

```
define('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY', 'your_consumer_key');  
define('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET', 'your_consumer_secret');
```

More info [here](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html#create)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not authenticated,
first authenticate then try to post updates.
I didn't use EpiTwitter but this error seems nothing to do with different charsets,